# Category is special word in ASP.NET MVC2? So how can I use something else?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

I have just realized that, by chance, I implemented a category browse type situation in my project:

```
// GET: /Category/Browse?Category=Fruit
public ActionResult Browse(string category)
{
    ...
}
```

It turns out this is special case and there must be something behind the scenes. My next one I want to implement something like

```
//GET: /Category/Browse?Color=Blue
public ActionResult Browse(string color)
{
   ...
}
```

You get the idea...

Where/how do I register the different url values?

Comment: for the time being i am just using the category value for everything :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register anything. Action parameters are automatically mapped to URL values by the default model binder. You can also map to [complex type, list and dictionary](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) parameters.